# Debugging WCF service

Tags: vb.net, web-services, wcf

I have a WCF web service that works locally but not on the live server and I need to debug it to figure out why. Reading the documentation I learned how I can add something to my web config file. Previously it looks like this:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings/>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
<services>
  <service name="MyService">
    <endpoint address="MyService.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="MyService">
    </endpoint>
  </service>
</services>
```

In order to add debugging capabilities the documentation told me to do the following:

1. Give the service behaviour a name.
2. Add behaviorConfiguration with that name to my service.
3. Change includeExceptionDetailInFaults to true.

I did that and this is the new code:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings/>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="test">
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
<services>
  <service name="MyService" behaviorConfiguration="test">
    <endpoint address="MyService.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="MyService">
    </endpoint>
  </service>
</services>
```

However when I now try and update my service reference I get the following error:

"The HTML document does not contain Web service discovery information. Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'MyService.svc'. Content Type application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8 was not supported by service MyService.svc. The client and service bindings may be mismatched. The remote service returned an error: (415) Cannot process the message because the content type 'application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8' was not the expected type 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'..

What the heck? If I remove the things the documentation told me to add then I can update the service reference just fine. The mind boggles. Who knows what on earth is going on here?

Comment: The endpoint address should be the `http://host_uri/service_name`.

Comment: You could also enable [**tracing**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx). Apart from that, you could also look in the request logs of IIS to see what kind of requests are made. Maybe the endpoint is just wrongly configured on the client.

Comment: I did change the end point to be http: etc. Here's the thing though: the web service works to a degree if I remove some code, I get a response back. So there's nothing wrong with the end point and setting up the service itself. But when I add in the debug tags all hell breaks loose.

Comment: I can't figure out how to add tracing. The link you put there leads to an article which is confusing and assumes prior knowledge so I am probably doing it wrong. I added this to my config file:

Comment: <system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel"
              switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing"
              propagateActivity="true">
        <listeners>
          <add name="traceListener"
              type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
              initializeData= "c:\log\Traces.svclog" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
  </system.diagnostics>

Comment: And then ran my service but c:log was empty.

Comment: Any help would be appreciated!